# Chord sounding weirdly/ how to read those notes (Piano)

Tags: piano, chords, chord-theory, sheet-music, self-learning

So I've got some notes I would like to play on my piano, but when I do, it sounds quite weird. Maybe I'm not playing to good notes, maybe I'm mistaking when I'm reading the sheet. The two sharps at the begining might get me wrong. May anyone help me?

## Notes I would like to play

[image]

## Notes I'm playing

[image]
*I am french, sorry for the example with the french notes (DO, RE, MI ...)*

Comment: Be careful with your wording:  the piece is notated with **two sharps**, C# and F# . The term **double sharp** means a note that has been raised by two half-steps.

Comment: Don't worry, Do-Re-Mi should be fairly commonly understood in the english-speaking world too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLm07s8fnzM :)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma ahah okay, I didn't knew that!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have sharpened the low C but not the higher. The highest note should be C#, not C. The key signature applies to all Fs and Cs, not only those aligned with the key signature. Additionally, the middle note you are playing is F, but it should be E.

Comment: The middle note should also be an E, not a F natural.

Comment: Yes - it's a very awkward graphic to read, somehow.